# How to pass a JQuery array to Apex controller

Tags: visualforce, jquery

I want to jq array in controller class to fetch all data and based on data create multiple data. to make this happen i tried this logic but m not able to convert string to list  can anyone plzz suggest me where i did a mistake.

here is my code:
vf page code:

```
<div>  
<button class="abc" id="btn-submit-offers"  onClick="onOffersSubmit()" type="button">Send All </button>
</div>

<apex:form>
    <apex:actionFunction name="actionFunction" action="{!saveOffer}">
        <apex:param name="firstParam" assignTo="{!saveOfferData}" value=""/>
    </apex:actionFunction>

</apex:form>

<script>
  (function () {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', onDOMContentLoaded);
    function onDOMContentLoaded() {
    var btnSubmitOffers = $('#btn-submit-offers');

    btnSubmitOffers.click(onOffersSubmit);

    function onOffersSubmit() {
          var arr=[];
          $(".forms-wrapper").children().each((i,e)=>{
              console.log(i);
              console.log(e);
              var a = [];     
              $(e).find("input, select").each((i,e)=>{ a.push(e.value) });
          arr.push(a); });
        arr.shift();
        console.log(arr);
        actionFunction(arr.toString());
        alert('Hello from Submit');
      }
```

and this is my controller class:

```
public class BankPortalOfferBuilder {

 public String Saveoff{get; set;}
public String[] offerCreates{get;set;}

 public BankPortalOfferBuilder(){

offerCreates =new List<String>();
}

 public void saveOfferData(){
        offerCreates =convertStrToList(Saveoff);
    }
public String [] saveOffer(String str)
    {
    String[] Values = new List<String>();
    if(String.isNotBlank(str)) {
        for(String eachStr : str.split(',')) {
            Values.add(eachStr);
        }
    }

        System.debug(values);     
        Bank_Partner_Offer__c offer1=[Select id,Offer_Sent__c from Bank_Partner_Offer__c where id=:Values[0]];
        if(offer1.Offer_Sent__c!=true)
        {
            Bank_Partner_Offer__c clickedOffer1 = new Bank_Partner_Offer__c();
            clickedOffer1.id = Values[0];
            clickedOffer1.Bank_Partner_Application__c=bpapp[0].Id;
            clickedOffer1.Offer_Amount__c = Double.valueOf(Values[1]);
            clickedOffer1.Payback_Amount__c = Double.valueOf(Values[2]);
            clickedOffer1.Percentage_Rate__c = Double.valueOf(Values[3]);
            clickedOffer1.Duration_Type__c=Values[5];
            clickedOffer1.Duration1__c = Values[4];
            clickedOffer1.Payment_Frequency__c=Values[6];
            update clickedOffer1;  
            getBankPartnerOffers();
        }
    }
```

in controller class i think m not using proper approach to fetch the data. so if someone help in tht field also then its good for me.

Comment: Please do take the time to format your code (using Ctrl-K or the `{]` button) so that others can read it. I would also strongly recommend you read through [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to edit your question to be very specific about what you're trying to do and what isn't working, including any specific error messages verbatim.

Answer (score 0):

I have to first be honest and say I didn't read you're entire question.

You said "convert string to list" which makes me think you're successfully getting your information in the controller but don't know what to do with it.

Use the [JSON class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm) to parse the string and convert it into something Apex can use. I have [this answer over here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/227588/24107) explaining a bit more about converting strings to usable apex.