# how to read this dynamic JSON

Tags: json

We used to deserialize the JSON when we know the object type . but this JSON is dynamic and I have to get the object name,fieldname and its values and store it in any collection where I can reuse it later.

```
{
    "Header": {
        "Assessment": "A-1035",
        "Type": "Assessment",
        "SFID": "a3C4C0000000ZHZUA2",
        "FarmName": "Universal Farms",
        "UserName": "Roy Human",
        "UserEmail": "roy.human@example.com",
        "UserID": "00544000007wwMAAAY"
    },
    "Attributes": {
        "Bedding": 0,
        "Stalls": 0
    },
    "Data": [
        ["COWS_Assessment__c.ID",
            "a3C4C0000000ZHZUA2"
        ],
        ["COWS_Assessment__c.Name",
            "A-1035"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.A_Notes__c",
            "a test that includes \"quotes\" in a text box."
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.A_Benchmark_Type__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.A_Assessment_Date__c",
            ""
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.A_Interviewee_Name__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.A_Interviewee_Title__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.A_Interviewer__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.A_PenNumName__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.A_Assessment_Type__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.A_Valid_Benchmark__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.CIP_Bulls_AggrCows__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.CIP_FirstLact__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.CIP_MilkingTimes__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.CIP_MilkingTimesperDay__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.CIP_NumCowsInPen__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.CIP_PenAveFat__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.CIP_PenAveLact__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.CIP_PenAveMilk__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.CIP_PenAveProtein__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.CIP_PenAveSCC__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.CIP_PenDescription__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.Hock_Score_1__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.Hock_Score_2__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.Hock_Score_3__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.MC_BreedOfMajority__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.MC_FarmAveDIM__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.MC_FarmAveLact__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.MC_FarmAveMilk__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.MC_NumCowsAssessed__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.MC_NumCowsMilked__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.MC_TotalCowsInHerd__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.Parlor_BarnType__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.Parlor_FeedingFreq__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.Parlor_FeedingTimes__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.Parlor_NumUnits__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.Parlor_PushUpFreq__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.Parlor_Type__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.Parlor_YearBarnBuilt__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.PE_HoldingAreaCooling__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.PE_PenCooling__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.PE_HoldingFanTemp__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.PE_HoldingSprinklerTemp__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.PE_PenFanTemp__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Assessment__c.PE_PenSprinklerTemp__c",
            "null"
        ],
        ["COWS_Farm__c.Name",
            "Kambro Farms"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Farm__c.Contact_Person__c",
            "Tom Kampman"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Farm__c.Contact_Role__c",
            "General Manager"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Farm__c.Farm_Address__c",
            "33344 Township Rd."
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Farm__c.Farm_City__c",
            "Abbotsford"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Farm__c.Farm_State__c",
            "BC"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Farm__c.Farm_Zip_Code__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Farm__c.Farm_Phone__c",
            "(604) 768-9093"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Farm__c.Farm_Email__c",
            "kambro_farms@live.com"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Farm__c.Producer_Name__c",
            "Tom Kampman"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Farm__c.Farm_Type__c",
            "Freestall"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Farm__c.Consultant_Name__c",
            "Steve"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Farm__c.Consultant_Phone_Number__c",
            "(604) 217-6757"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Farm__c.Consultant_Email__c",
            "steve@dairysmartnutrition.com"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Farm__c.Farm_Mailing_Address__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Farm__c.Farm_Mailing_City__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Farm__c.Farm_Mailing_State__c",
            "null"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Farm__c.Farm_Mailing_Zip_Code__c",
            "null"
        ],
        ["COWS_Farm__c.Notes__c",
            "Products used: Alimet, Mintrex, Santoquin.\nEnter the farm through the south gate."
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Farm__c.Number_of_Employees__c",
            "32"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Farm__c.Products_Used__c",
            "Antioxidants;Minerals;Vitamins;Essential Oils"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Farm__c.Veterinarian__c",
            "AgWest Veterinarian Group"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Farm__c.Novus_Sales_Manager__c",
            "Clemence Nash"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Farm__c.Company_Name__c",
            "AAA Egg"
        ],
        [
            "COWS_Farm__c.Business_Opportunity__c",
            "Prospect"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Maybe take a look at https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/ ?

Comment: If you have a dynamic JSON everytime, then that's an issue in itself. Because if you are expecting a JSON, it should follow a schema. And with whatever wrapper class you write, you need to make sure that all those fields which you expect to deserialize are present in the JSON. When you say dynamic - what exactly changes every time?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to go ahead and assume that the structure of the JSON is relatively constant, regardless of the object/fields?
Following this general syntax:

```
{
  Header:{...},
  Attributes:{...},
  Data:[
    ['Field','Value'],  // Are you sure this isn't {'Field':'Value'} ?
  ],
}
```

This is where generic sObjects come in handy.

You can use `sObject.put(fieldName,value)` to assign field values to the generic sObject type by their name.

When initializing the sObject, you can use `Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectType).newSObject()` to create an instance of it from a String of the object type.

Then, once you convert the JSON into a Salesforce equivalent to iterate over, you can simply init a new sObject, and then iterate over your data to dynamically assign the field values, assuming they map to a Salesforce Object!

Here is a very basic example showing loading data into the account object this way:

```
    String json_string = '{"Header":{"type":"Account"},"Data":[["Name","Hello World!"]]}';

    // Break the JSON String into a Map
    Map<String,Object> json_object = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(json_string);      

    // It further breaks down into another Map and a List      
    List<Object> Data = (List<Object>)json_object.get('Data');
    Map<String,Object> Header = (Map<String,Object>)json_object.get('Header');

    // Get object type and initialize an sObject
    String obj_type = (String)Header.get('type');        
    sObject obj = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(obj_type).newSObject();

    // Iterate through the data and dynamically assign fields
    for (Object d : Data) {
        List<Object> field_value = (List<Object>)d;
        obj.put((String)field_value[0],(String)field_value[1]);
    }

    insert obj;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: here is an answer I prepared on Dynamic Json that i use to answer questions like this. I'm adding it as a comment here since your answer is the best answer submitted. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/227588/24107