# how to pass deseralize Json into Other methods

Tags: apex, integration

Got confuse about JSON deseralization value is passing to other methods
. Please check my question below.  How to pass deseralized Json into other method,This is my deseralized Json

Apex Class:

```
global class RecordIDS {
    string vmstarid;
    string gsid;
}

global class ReadPRBugResponse {
    List < RecordIDS > PRDetails;
    List < RecordIDS > BugDetails;
    String responseMessage;
    String status;
}

if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {...}
```

Getting following Response Like this:

```
JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
```

gives following response

```
{
   "prDetails":[
      {
         "gsid":"pr1gsid",
         "vmstarid":"pr1vmstarid"
      },
      {
         "gsid":" pr2gsid ",
         "vmstarid":" pr2vmstarid "
      }
   ],
   "bugDetails":[
      {
         "gsid":"bugzilla1gsid",
         "vmstarid":" bugzilla1vmstarid "
      },
      {
         "gsid":" bugzilla2gsid",
         "vmstarid":" bugzilla2vmstarid"
      }
   ],
   "responseMessage":"",
   "status":""
}
```

How to pass pr details in below method and also need to update the vmstar I'd based on corresponding accountid

```
//PrDetails
public static string Prdetails(Listofgsid, list of vmstarid) {
    List < Account > acList = [
        select id, vmstarid 
        from account 
        where id in: Listofgsid
    ];

    //if this pr1gsid, I need to update pr1vmstarid
    //if this pr2gsid, I need to update pr2vmstarid

}
```

Is it correct?after this part I got confuse ,how to send values to  other methods.

Comment: Are you asking how to deserialize a JSON response into Apex objects? This is pretty unclear.

Comment: updated the question

Comment: updated the question..iam new to integration,just added the code

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/227588/24107

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you close, I will try to answer questions about the code but I won't write any more code for you.

```
global class bugZillaResponse {
    List<bugZillaDetail> prDetails {get; set;}
    List<bugZillaDetail> bugDetails {get; set;}
}

global class bugZillaDetail {
    public String gsid {get; set;}
    public String vmstarid {get; set}
}
```

Then:

```
public static string updateRecords(List<bugZillaDetail> details) {
    Set<String> gsids = new Set<String>();

    for (bugZillaDetail bzd : details) {
        gsids.add(bzd.gsid);
    }

    Map<Id, Account> acMap = [
        select id, vmstarid 
        from account 
        where id in:gsids
    ];

    for (bugZillaDetail bzd : prDetails) {
        acMap.get(bzd.gsid).vmstarid__c = bzd.vmstarid;
    }

    update acMap.values();
}
```

Finally:

```
bugZillaResponse bzResponse = JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(), bugZillaResponse.class);

updateRecords(bzResponse.prDetails);
updateRecords(bzResponse.bugDetails);
```

Comment: but  getting this exception: Error Error: Compile Error: Illegal assignment from Object to CasePRBugzilla_RestService.ReadPRBugResponse at line 122 column 30

Comment: Generally speaking that error means you need to typecast the object. You'll have to create a new question and provide an example of what your code looks like on 122 for specific help. The answer will usually look like `string test = (String) Object;` This syntax tells the compiler that the object is the string. Again, youll have to adapt it to your use case.