# How to parse Json response and insert Record in apex?

Tags: apex, rest-api, json

I need to read the json response(response will be for one record) from Rest API and need to insert record in salesforce.
I tried using below, but unable to get fields.

Json response:

```
"Vehicle":[
  {
    "Name_1":"Test",
    "field1":{
      "name":"Testing ABC"
      "alias":"Testing ABC"
      },
    "field2":{
      "name":"Testing 123"
      "alias":"Testing 123"
      },
    "field3":{
      "name":"xyz"
      "alias":"xyz"
      },
    "field4":{
      "Name":"apple" 
      "alias":"apple"         
    }
    ]
```

Apex code:

```
String name = 'Test'; 
                            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
                            HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
                            Http http = new Http();
                            req.setEndpoint('url');
                            req.setMethod('POST');
                            String r='{"getdetail":{';
                                r+='"name":'+name; 
                                r+='}}';
                            req.setBody(r);
                            req.setCompressed(true);
                            res = http.send(req);
                            String str = res.getBody();
                            System.debug('res'+str);// I am able to get above json response
                            Map<String, Object> m =   (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(str);
                            System.debug('---->>>>debug'+m.get('Name_1')); // it is returing null
```

Comment: Use this [JSON2Apex](http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/) tool to create a utility class to parse the JSON. Once you could parse the JSON string, it would be easy extract values to create a record.

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/227588/24107 This answer goes over some details regarding JSON deserialization and the question, comments and other answers have plenty of information.

Answer (score 1):

You missed two outer levels of structure in your JSON.

```
Map<String, Object> m =   (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(str);
System.debug('---->>>>debug'+m.get('Name_1')); // it is returing null
```

The top-level JSON object doesn't contain the key `Name_1`. It contains the key `Vehicle`, whose value is a `List<Object>`. The only value in that list is the `Map<String, Object>` containing the key `Name_1`.

As recommended by Arnold Jr. in the comments, you'll have an easier time if you use typed deserialization (`JSON.deserialize()`) into an Apex class that matches this structure, which a tool like JSON2Apex can generate for you.

You can use untyped deserialization, but you'll need to descend each layer of the JSON structure, casting your types along the way so that you can drill into the List and then the Map.